# Uniform Probobility Distribution Word Problem, grocery store checkout and meeting a friend

Tags: uniform-distribution, word-problem

1. The amount of time spent waiting in line at a grocery store express checkout varies from 5 minutes to 15 minutes and follows a uniform distribution. Let X be the amount of time spent waiting in line.

f)  Suppose you arrive at the express checkout (with less than 8 items, of course) at 5:00 p.m. and have plans to meet a friend at the food court at 5:20 p.m. If it takes 6 minutes for your groceries to be scanned and paid for and 2 minutes to walk from the store to the food court, what is the probability you will be on time to meet your friend?

Since it is uniform I have sketched the graph in my notes and found that the Height of the uniform distribution is 1/10...but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: first calculate the net time $t$ you have left for queueing after accounting for the scanning and walking. Then calculate the probability that your actual queueing time $X$ is less than or equal to $t.$

Comment: What do you mean by 'queueing'...scanning and walking is (6 min scanning + 2 min walking) = 8 min

Comment: Queueing is a synonym for waiting in line, sorry for the jargon

Comment: So do you mean that for the first part the net time I have waiting in line is: (6 min scanning + 2 min walking) = 8 min, so I would use that 8 min taken away from 5:20 pm when I meet the friend, which would be 5:12pm

Comment: The net time you have left to lose in the waiting line before you stand up your friend is 20 minutes minus these 8 minutes, i.e., 12 minutes. If the waiting time is longer than that, you lose. If it is shorter, you win.

Comment: Sorry, but what do I do to calculate the probability that the queueing time is less than or equal to 12 min?

Comment: You use the fact that the random queueing time is uniformly distributed between 5 min and 15 min.

Comment: So on my graph that I sketched for between 5 and 15 min for which I found the height is 1/10, I would use that to look at the amount of time waiting is between 5 and 12 min? Which I found is 7/10, is that correct?

Comment: Yep, I think you're there.